# Error while including maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add map view to my react native project, It works well on ios but when I try to run on android its failing, In that image when I comment out the marked statement  the project is compiling successfully when I included its shows me an error

[image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kl7E5Q5XR0XWLPzW-7BuN-AXoiU-vBLW)

Comment: Please add build.gradle( module:react-native-map)

Comment: its already included @VishalDhanotiya

Comment: You have added project level build.gradle file image but actual problem is in build.gradle of react-native-maps copy the code of build.gradle(Module:react-native-maps)( third one gradle view hierarchy ) and update with you question